# How to Set Azure Data Factory Schedule Between Intervals

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is is possible to set a schedule in Azure Data Factory to execute a pipeline at intervals?

For example, I would like to schedule that runs every hour from Monday to Friday between 9am and 5am

At the moment I the following, but not sure how to enter the execution times.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look something like that:
[image: shedule trigger]